PDF generation through Nextjs
am trying to generate a pdf from a nextjs component , the problem is the image won't show at all inside the pdf .
the image is shown in the UI through the link provided inside the processedImage( from aws s3)
it shows correctly inside the UI  but when i download the pdf it won't show at all
this is the code :
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Dropzone, FileCard } from '@files-ui/react';
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
import html2pdf from 'html2pdf.js';

export default function ColorExtraction() {
    const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
    const [processedImage, setProcessedImage] = useState(null);
    const [colorCodes, setColorCodes] = useState([]);
    const [colorDisparities, setColorDisparities] = useState([]);
    const [overallDisparity, setOverallDisparity] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const contentRef = useRef(null);

    const handleColorExtraction = async () => {
        if (files.length > 0) {
            const selectedFile = files[0].file;
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', selectedFile);

            setIsLoading(true);

            try {
                const ColorExtractionResponse = await fetch('/api/Color-identification', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData,
                });

                if (!ColorExtractionResponse.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`Color Extraction API failed with status ${ColorExtractionResponse.status}`);
                }

                const ColorExtractionData = await ColorExtractionResponse.json();
                const resId = ColorExtractionData.id;
                const listFilesResponse = await fetch('/api/Color-files', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ id: resId }),
                });

                if (!listFilesResponse.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`Color-files API failed with status ${listFilesResponse.status}`);
                }

                const result = await listFilesResponse.json();
                setProcessedImage(result.processedImageUrl);
                setColorCodes(result.colorCodes);

                const disparities = calculateColorDisparities(result.colorCodes);
                setColorDisparities(disparities);

                const overall = calculateOverallDisparity(disparities);
                setOverallDisparity(overall.toFixed(2));
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error in color extraction process:', error);
            } finally {
                setIsLoading(false);
            }
        }
    };

    const calculateColorDisparities = (codes) => {
        const disparities = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < codes.length - 1; i++) {
            const rgb1 = hexToRgb(codes[i]);
            const rgb2 = hexToRgb(codes[i + 1]);

            const normalizedR1 = rgb1.r / 255;
            const normalizedG1 = rgb1.g / 255;
            const normalizedB1 = rgb1.b / 255;

            const normalizedR2 = rgb2.r / 255;
            const normalizedG2 = rgb2.g / 255;
            const normalizedB2 = rgb2.b / 255;

            const disparity = ((Math.abs(normalizedR1 - normalizedR2) +
                                Math.abs(normalizedG1 - normalizedG2) +
                                Math.abs(normalizedB1 - normalizedB2)) / 3) * 100;

            disparities.push(disparity);
        }
        return disparities;
    };

    const hexToRgb = (hex) => {
        const bigint = parseInt(hex.substring(1), 16);
        const r = (bigint >> 16) & 255;
        const g = (bigint >> 8) & 255;
        const b = bigint & 255;
        return { r, g, b };
    };

    const calculateOverallDisparity = (disparities) => {
        if (disparities.length === 0) return 0;

        const sum = disparities.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
        const averageDisparity = sum / disparities.length;

        return averageDisparity;
    };

    const handleFilesChange = (incomingFiles) => {
        setFiles(incomingFiles);
    };

    const handleCancel = () => {
        setFiles([]);
    };

    const removeProcessedImage = () => {
        setProcessedImage(null);
        setColorCodes([]);
        setColorDisparities([]);
        setOverallDisparity(null);
    };

    const createColorDisparityChart = (colorDisparities, colorCodes) => {
        const labels = colorCodes.slice(1).map((code, index) => `${colorCodes[index]} - ${code}`);
        const canvas = document.getElementById('colorDisparityChart') as HTMLCanvasElement;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        if (!ctx) {
            console.error('Failed to get 2D context for canvas');
            return;
        }

        new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Disparity Percentage',
                    data: colorDisparities,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: 'Disparity Percentage'
                        }
                    },
                    x: {
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: 'Color Pairs'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isLoading && processedImage && colorDisparities.length > 0) {
            createColorDisparityChart(colorDisparities, colorCodes);
        }
    }, [isLoading, processedImage, colorDisparities, colorCodes]);

    const downloadPDF = () => {
        const element = contentRef.current;
    
        if (!element) {
            console.error('Content element not found.');
            return;
        }
    
        // Ensure image is loaded before generating PDF
        const image = new Image();
        image.src = processedImage;
        image.onload = () => {
            const opt = {
                margin: 1,
                filename: 'color_extraction.pdf',
                image: { type: 'jpg', quality: 0.98 },
                html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
                jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'landscape' }
            };
    
            html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();
        };
    };
    

    return (
        <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto relative">
            {isLoading ? (
                <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
                    <img src="/loading1.gif" alt="Loading" className="w-48 h-48" />
                </div>
            ) : (
                <div ref={contentRef}>
                    {processedImage ? (
                        <div id="dropzone-content" className="bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md p-8 mb-8 relative">
                            <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-20 relative">
                                <div className="col-span-1 flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
                                    <img
                                        src={processedImage}
                                        alt="Processed Result"
                                        className="max-w-full max-h-[35rem] mb-4 mx-auto"
                                        style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
                                    />
                                    <div className="text-sm text-gray-600 text-center">
                                        {colorCodes.length > 0 && (
                                            <div>
                                                <h2 className="font-semibold">Hex Codes:</h2>
                                                <ul className="flex justify-center">
                                                    {colorCodes.map((code, index) => (
                                                        <li key={index} style={{ backgroundColor: code, width: '20px', height: '20px', margin: '0 5px' }}></li>
                                                    ))}
                                                </ul>
                                                <p className="mt-2">Overall Disparity: {overallDisparity}%</p>
                                            </div>
                                        )}
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div className="col-span-1 flex justify-center items-center h-full">
                                    <div className="text-center">
                                        <canvas id="colorDisparityChart" width="500" height="300" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <Dropzone
                            id="dropzone-content"
                            onChange={handleFilesChange}
                            value={files}
                            className={` bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md `}
                            style={{ maxHeight: '400px' }}
                        >
                            {files.map((file) => (
                                <FileCard {...file} preview key={file.id} />
                            ))}
                        </Dropzone>
                    )}

                    {!isLoading && !processedImage && (
                        <div className="flex justify-end">
                            <button className="bg-indigo-400 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded mt-4 hover:bg-indigo-500" onClick={handleColorExtraction}>
                                Extract Colors
                            </button>
                            <button className="bg-red-400 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded ml-2 mt-4 hover:bg-red-500" onClick={handleCancel}>
                                Cancel
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            )}

            {processedImage && (
                <div className="flex justify-center mt-4">
                    <button className="bg-indigo-400 text-white ml-3 px-6 py-2 rounded ml-4 mt-4 hover:bg-indigo-500" onClick={downloadPDF}>
                        Download PDF
                    </button>
                    <button className="bg-red-400 text-white ml-3 px-6 py-2 rounded mt-4 hover:bg-red-500" onClick={removeProcessedImage}>
                        Cancel
                    </button>
                    
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}


i have tried some fixes regarding the async nature of the loading for the image (tried to make it generate pdf only if the image is fully loaded ) but still no change .

I think your example is a bit longish, try to create a minimal reproducible case (should link to the SO help)
